# Why does RSolve not give what I expect?

Tags: difference-equations

I have a model based on a digraph `G`. I construct a system of difference equations, `modelFull`, as seen below.

```
ClearAll[n, d, G, aG, aGsym, Xt, gama, teta, tao, alfa, one, eta, 
  onePlusEta, Aterm, Bterm, Cterm, Dterm, Xt1];
SeedRandom[14];
n = 10;
d = 0.3;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges -> True];
aG = AdjacencyMatrix[G];
aGsym = BitAnd[aG, Transpose[aG]]; (* by @Coolwater *)

Xt = DiagonalMatrix[Array[Subscript[x, #][t] &, n]];
alfa = Transpose@Array[\[Alpha][#] &, {n, n}];
eta = Array[\[Eta][#] &, n];
gama = Transpose[Array[\[Gamma][#] &, {n, n}]]*aG;
tao = Array[\[Tau][#] &, {n, n}];
teta = Transpose[Array[\[Theta][#] &, {n, n}]*aG];
one = Array[1 &, n];

onePlusEta = DiagonalMatrix[one + eta]*Xt;
Aterm = (gama + teta).Xt;  
Bterm = Xt.((alfa*tao)*aG); 
Cterm = ((alfa*alfa)*aGsym)*(Xt.Array[Diagonal[Xt] &, {n}])*aGsym;  
Dterm = ((gama*gama)*aGsym)*Transpose[Array[(Subscript[x, #][t])^2 &, {n, n}]*aGsym];

Xt1 = Array[Subscript[x, #][t + 1] &, n]; 
eqs = Total[onePlusEta - Aterm + Bterm + Cterm - Dterm]; 
modelFull = Thread[Xt1 == eqs];
```

So far, everything works fine. I have all my difference equations in `modelFull`. Then I parametrize the `modelFull` as follows:

```
ClearAll[params, parameters, sol];
params = {abs, random, absCost, trsCost, trs} = 
   {
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n],       
    RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, n],  
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n],    
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n],    
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n]     
    };
  parameters = Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@Thread[Array[#,n] & /@
      {\[Alpha], \[Eta], \[Gamma], \[Tau], \[Theta]} ->params]];
```

Then I construct `RSolve` as:

```
  sol = RSolve[{modelFull /. parameters, Array[Subscript[x, #][0] == 1 &, n]} // Flatten, 
      Array[Subscript[x, #][t] &, n], t] // Flatten
```

The output from this `RSolve` is:

> ReplaceAll::reps: {RSolve[{Subscript[x, 1][1+t]==-2.84077 Subscript[x, 1][t]-0.38506 Subscript[<<2>>][<<1>>]^2+0.441027 Subscript[x, 2][t]+0.513668 Subscript[x, 3][t]+0.818674 Subscript[x, 4][t]+0.343748 Subscript[x, 7][t]+0.977052 Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 7][t]+0.817954 Subscript[x, 8][t]+0.977052 Subscript[x, 1][t] Subscript[x, 8][t]+0.101168 Subscript[x, 9][t],<<18>>,Subscript[x, 10][0]==1},{Subscript[x, 1][t],Subscript[x, 2][t],Subscript[x, 3][t],<<5>>,Subscript[x, 9][t],Subscript[x, 10][t]},t]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> RSolve::dsvar: 1.0001838571428572` cannot be used as a variable. >>

What is missing/wrong in my `code`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  Try running your code in a fresh notebook.  However, `RSolve` appears to be unable to solve the nonlinear problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: I will do your suggestion now and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: TIP: don't use subscripts.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: I still receive the same errors. No change.

Comment: Did you restart Mathematica and copy the code from your question to the fresh notebook?

Comment: @AccidentalFourier: Without subscripts, how would you write `Array[Subscript[x, #][t] &, n]]` where subscripts are for objects (firms or countries) and t is for time.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Yes, I quit Kernel and run it again and then copied the `code` to a fresh notebook. No change at all.

Comment: @TugrulTemel For example, `Array[x[#][t] &, 3]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: I copied the `code` from the post and run it. This time strangely enough I did not receive any error but the `RSolve` returns the model equations without any solution. But no errors exist any more.

Comment: I'm glad that your code is running now.  As I already mentioned, `RSolve` returns unevaluated. `RecurrenceTable`, on the other hand, yields numerical values, although they grow exponentially in magnitude.

Comment: @AccidentalFourier: Thanks very much for the `Array`. I will try it now. Thank you.